# National Instruments on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

National Instruments have been Windows only for a while. Now you can get [drivers(2018)](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-linux-device-drivers-2018/7664/en/) and libraries([1](http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/54754/en/),[2](http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/52786/en/)) for Linux. Unfortunately, they only support [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop + Workstation    6.x, 7.x
CentOS  7.x OpenSUSE Leap   42.2, 42.3](http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/52786/en/) and not Ubuntu.

One can download all .rpm files and using [alien](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/) convert them to .deb and install them. However, there are several problems with that. One of them is `trying to overwrite '/bin/cpio', which is also in package cpio` see example below.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends nivisa_15.0.0-2_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 138232 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nivisa_15.0.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nivisa (15.0.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive nivisa_15.0.0-2_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/bin/cpio', which is also in package cpio 2.12+dfsg-6
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nivisa_15.0.0-2_all.deb
```

The possible solution to  `trying to overwrite '/bin/cpio', which is also in package cpio` is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in) however, CPIO is an import library and here what I got when I tried to remove it.

```
sudo dpkg -P cpio
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of cpio:
 ubuntu-standard depends on cpio.
 initramfs-tools-core depends on cpio.
 alien depends on cpio.
```

The bigger question is: Has anyone tried to install NI packages on Ubuntu?